# Communication between asynch I/O

Tags: json, go, io

I'm having a bit of an issue with using the io.MultiWriter together with channels to communicate between the different routines using the readers. I'm trying to build an upload function which receives a JSON, writes it to disk, but at the same time checks what mime type it is and creates a thumbnail. So

```
getUploadData(...)
```

Grabs the mime string from the JSON and writes it to the mimeChan channel, which is then received by

```
makeAndSaveTbn(...)
```

which will then make a different thumbnail depending on the mime.

At the same time

```
saveOnDisk(...)
```

Just saves the file to disk. Since I'm streaming to three routines I am using the io.Pipes together with io.MultiWriter.

Now the issue is simply that makeAndSaveTbn(...) never receives the message from the channel mimeChan and blocks the program. The writing to the channel works, if I remove the dependency on mimeChan and just receive it in ProcessUpload(...) it works.

Is there maybe an issue with the io.Writers in a sense that they actually can't be read asynchronously ?

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated, thanks for already reading this fare!

My process upload function looks like this :

```
func ProcessUpload(r *File) (err error) {

sr, sw := io.Pipe()
tr, tw := io.Pipe()
pr, pw := io.Pipe()

mimeChan := make(chan string, 1)
done := make(chan string)
defer close(done)
defer close(mimeChan)

go getUploadData(pr, mimeChan, done)
go saveOnDisk(sr, done)
go makeAndSaveTbn(tr, FileID, mimeChan, done)

go func() {
    defer sw.Close()
    defer tw.Close()
    defer pw.Close()
    mw := io.MultiWriter(pw, tw, sw)
    _, err := io.Copy(mw, r)

    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
}()

for c := 0; c < 3; c++ {
    log.Errorf(<-done)
}


return err
}
```

The mime checker looks like this:

```
func getUploadData(pr *io.PipeReader, mimeChan chan string, done chan string) {
    var p uploadParams
    err := json.NewDecoder(pr).Decode(&p)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
    log.Errorf(p.Mime)
    done <- "getUploadData"
    mimeChan <- p.Mime
}
```

And the blocking function like this, it receives the channel in if string.Contains...:

```
func makeAndSaveTbn(tr *io.PipeReader, FileID string, mimeChan chan string, done chan string) {
    if strings.ContainsAny(<-mimeChan, "image") {
        tbn, err := MakeThumbnail(tr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error(err)
        }
    done <- "makeAndSaveTbn"
    }
}
```

Comment: `makeAndSaveTbn` only conditionally sends to the channel. Try it properly with a `WaitGroup`, and log the steps when you encounter any problems.

Comment: io.Pipe specifies in its documentation that it's a synchronous pipe, and multiwriter simply loops over the writers provided and writes to them.  So all of them need to be receiving at the same time or the write will block on whichever isn't yet ready.

Comment: Sometimes concurrency is not the right tool.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Yeah, it looks like I either have to scratch the concurrency or buffer on all of the receivers.

Comment: But in principle, does anyone know of a good example on how to multiplex streaming a reader to different routines which execute at differs speeds? It does not seem like such an exotic thing to do.